# Make a TabBarItem selected at startup

Tags: iphone, ios4, tabbar, selecteditem

I work on a project for iPhone iOS4 with Xcode 4.

I created a UITabBar, with three UITabBarItem, in IB. I don't have  UITabBarControllerDelegate as delegate, but MainViewController.

Then I implement in MainViewController:

```
 - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
     switch (item.tag) {
         case 1:
             [scrollView setContentOffset:(CGPointMake (0,0))];
             break;
         case 2:
            [scrollView setContentOffset:(CGPointMake (320,0))];
             break;
         case 3:
            [scrollView setContentOffset:(CGPointMake (640,0))];
             break;
         default:
             break;
       }
    NSLog(@"didSelectItem: %d", item.tag);
}
```

This works OK, as I want it.

But I'm not able to make a TabBarItem selected at startup (in viewDidLoad). I try

```
     [tabBar setSelectedItem:calc];
     [tabBar setSelectedItem:1];
```

(cal is an ivar of MainViewController) and others but none works. Any suggestion?

Thank you.

---

This is MainViewController.h

```
  #import "FlipsideViewController.h"
  #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
  #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

  @interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate>   {

     UITabBar *tabBar;
     UITabBarItem *diagBarItem;
     UITabBarItem *calcBarItem;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *diagBarItem;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *calcBarItem;

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item; 

 @end
```

Comment: what type is calc ? is it an NSNumber ? if so it needs to be [calc intValue]

Comment: Now I changed calc to calcBarItem and [tabBar setSelectedItem:calcBarItem] works!!. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `-setSelectedItem:` on your tab bar is used to move UITabBarItems to different spots on the tab bar programmatically.

To change the selected tab, you need to change the `selectedIndex` property on the instance of UITabBarController. The property `tabBarController` on `UIViewController` is automatically set by Interface Builder. Try this in `-viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = calc;
}
```

Comment: This give an error "Incompatible pointer too integer conversion".

Comment: I tried "self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;" This give no error, but at startup the item is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the selected tab on the `UITabBarController`, and not on the tab bar itself:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
```

As you said this does not work, are you sure you have connected the outlets in Interface Builder? (Assuming that you used that to create the tab bar)

Comment: You will need to post more code to look into this, as this _is_ the way to change tabs programmatically. If it does not work, there is some problem with your declarations. Can you post the header file, and maybe also your initialization code?

Comment: See above MainViewController.h

Comment: This is the problem. The tab bar items should be part of the UITabBarController. Normally, you should make the tab bar controller your root view controller, and depending on which tab is selected, this controller will display the appropriate views. I suggest you start off by a tab-based app template in Xcode, so you can see how it is implemented there

Answer (score -1):

Give this a shot!

```
tabBar.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: Don't works. Error: Property "selectedIndex" not found on object of type UITabBar. Xcode suggest "selectedItem" but this also don't works (incompatible integer to pointer conversion).

Comment: Neither works tabBar.selectedItem = calcBarItem; (calcBarItem is a property declared in MainViewController).